# What is the best practice to prevent repetition in functions in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

I am developing a bot using [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot). I am heavily repeating some parts of it. What are the best practices not to repeat?

Here is the sample of my two functions.

```
def logo_design(update, context):
    global keyboard
    query = update.callback_query
    keyboard[0][0] = InlineKeyboardButton(
        f'{emojize(":white_check_mark:", use_aliases=True)} Logo Design', callback_data='6')
    bot = context.bot
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    bot.edit_message_text(
        chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
        message_id=query.message.message_id,
        text="Please choose one of our services\n",
        reply_markup=reply_markup
    )


def mob_development(update, context):
    global keyboard
    query = update.callback_query
    keyboard[1][0] = InlineKeyboardButton(
        f'{emojize(":white_check_mark: Mobile Development", use_aliases=True)} ', callback_data='0')
    bot = context.bot
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    bot.edit_message_text(
        chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
        message_id=query.message.message_id,
        text="Please choose one of our services\n",
        reply_markup=reply_markup
    )

    return SECOND
```

As you can see I have repeated most lines of codes in function. I want to prevent it.

Comment: Before answering, please read https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the above approach what do you think?

Comment: You asking me?  Well I think there is something wrong about asking about "best practice" ... if that is the "approach" you are referring to.

Comment: I would create a function that takes care of the largely repetitive part

Comment: Yea ... there are various ways that you could refactor that code.  But "best practice" implies that you think that there is some kind of recipe you can follow to "prevent" this.  There isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can add one parameter like `type`, that will select which of the keyboard to use. Then your code will be.

```
# I have re-factored the formatting the code
def function_name(update, context, type):
    global keyboard
    query = update.callback_query

    if type == 0:
        keyboard[0][0] = InlineKeyboardButton(
            f'{emojize(":white_check_mark:", use_aliases=True)} Logo Design', 
                       callback_data='6')
    else:
        keyboard[1][0] = InlineKeyboardButton(
        f'{emojize(":white_check_mark: Mobile Development", use_aliases=True)} ', callback_data='0')

    bot = context.bot
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    bot.edit_message_text(
        chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
        message_id=query.message.message_id,
        text="Please choose one of our services\n",
        reply_markup=reply_markup
    )
```